# Nochmals zu reflexiven Pronomen

Tags: grammar-identification, dialect, reflexive

- *Es sieht so aus*
- *Das sieht mir so aus*
- *Sieht so aus.*

  Dies sind mehr oder weniger gleichberechtigte Varianten.
- “Es sieht sich so aus”

  Wird dad irgendwo regelmäßig verwendet? Die Suchmaschine liefert 1 Ergebnis:

  > Problem ist nur ... es sieht sich so aus das Recaro Sitze im Golf 2 unbekannt sind in Belgien

  (Luiwammes auf doppel-wobber.de, via google)

  Ist das Hyperkorrektur, wo genau? Oder sind vereinzelt derartige Abweichungen zu erwarten? Was für eine Pronome ist das, Adverbial?

Auf das Beispiel kommt es nicht an, sondern die Frage, ob es Regelmäßigkeit aufweist. Um weitere Beispiele wird gebeten.

Kleingedrucktes: Eine ähnliche Frage wurde zuvor ohne Angabe von hinreichenden Gründen geschlossen. "Needs Detail" ist ja gerade der Auftrag an den Antwortenden.

Die erneute Schließung ist halt auch besengt. Keines der in der vorigen Frage zur Antwort gestellten Beispielen entspricht dem hiesigen. Es ist dieses auch nicht das einzige Beispiel seiner Art, d.h. es ist definitiv nicht Standard aber – darin unterscheiden sich die Antworten zur vorigen Frage – es gibt gleichlautende Standardbeispiele ohne "sich".

---

Noch so a Beispiel. Vielleicht sammel ich die einfach mal hier, bis die Beweislast erd-rückend wird.

> Deset sind se sech der Sach a'jange

> *Deswegen sind sie die Sache angegangen* / *haben sie sich der Sache angenommen*

(Eifeler Platt)

Comment: Wenn deine Frage geschlossen wird heißt das eigentlich, editiere die Frage damit sie wieder geöffnet wird und nicht, eröffne eine neue (gleiche) Frage.

Comment: "es sieht sich aus" im obigen Zitat kommt vermutlich aus derselben Quelle wie das anschließende "das". Das ist nicht Hyperkorrektur, das ist RTL-II-Soziolekt. Müssen wir jetzt über jeden Rechtschreibfehler im Internet semiotisch-semiologische Abhandlungen verfassen?

Comment: "needs detail" ist mitnichten der "Auftrag an den Antwortenden"! "Ich möchte gern *irgendwas* wissen, sag mir möglichst detailliert, was es ist." Darauf kann man auch keine sinnvolle Antwort geben.